# How get array of reactions Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js, message

I want get info about reactions but i can't. I need get reaction and authors this reactions from old message without listeners or something.
This code make something similar https://gist.github.com/acollierr17/c9e7aaf9eba97d8659b59395b5f2046d but don't work for me, var is empty. But i can get message `m.channel.fetchMessage(ID)`
I don't understand why this does not work, although the message is received to var. How collect all reactions and their authors of message to array?

I try this and few other ways.

```
if(calcreact == 1 && msg.content.startsWith('/calcreact')) { //start
        calcreact = 0; // защита от флуда
        let msgid = finddata(msg.content);
         //let channel = 709517297664131082;
        msg.channel.fetchMessage(msgid)
            .then(m => {
        //console.log('Message:', message.content);
        

    let reactions = m.reactions;
    let reaction = reactions.first();
    let users = reaction.users.map((u) => u.toString());
        
        console.log(users);
        //console.log(m.reactions.fetch());
        //console.log(m.reactions.forEach((reaction) => {}));
        m.reactions.forEach((reaction) => console.log(reaction));
        m.reactions.forEach((reaction) => console.log(reaction.users));
        m.reactions.forEach((reaction) => console.log(reaction.users.map((u) => u.toString())) );
        
        //console.log('Reactions:', );
      });

        setTimeout(antiflood, 500, 'calcreact');
    } //end
```

From `m.reactions.forEach((reaction) => console.log(reaction));` i can get huge info "array" and in marked current reaction(It seems to me https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Jqs.png) but deep (users) empty. This is horrible...

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should probably add some of the code you've written to your question, not only a related example, as well as any errors your code throws. This will increase the likelihood of a helpful answer significantly

Comment: i try, but this is looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

The function bellow groups reactions by users, like this:

```
{
  userId1: ['reactionId1', 'reactionId2'],
  userId2: ['reactionId1', 'reactionId2'],
  ...
}
```

You can adapt this to get the users and reactions from messages, or any context you like.

**OBS: It was written in TypeScript, but if you remove the typing, it turns into JavaScript.**

Function:

```
import { MessageReaction } from "discord.js";

interface IReactionsByUsers {
  [userId: string]: Array<string>;
}

DiscordClient.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction: MessageReaction) => {
  const reducer = (acc: IReactionsByUsers, cur: [string, MessageReaction]) => {
    const [reactionId, reaction] = cur;

    const usersIds = [...reaction.users.cache].map(([userId]) => userId);

    for (const userId of usersIds) {
      if (acc[userId]) {
        acc[userId].push(reactionId);
      } else {
        acc[userId] = [reactionId];
      }
    }

    return acc;
  };

  const messageReactions = [...reaction.message.reactions.cache];

  const reactionByUsers = messageReactions.reduce(
    reducer,
    {} as IReactionsByUsers
  );

  return reactionByUsers;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use the client.on("messageReactionAdd" method and save the reactions in an array.

Comment: I can get old reactions or only new reactions ?

Comment: Readed some info about this method, this is can be get reactions from message after fetching this old message i think ? Or i wrong thinking ?

Comment: This Event is triggered, once a reaction is added to a message. Then you can get the Person that reacted.